# SortDescription with converter

Tags: wpf, converters, collectionviewsource

I have  `list<Person> Persons`

Person has ID, something like that:12231d4sa32fd

I have a converter that convert the ID to Status: (Ready/Waiting/NotHere).

I show the list in a ListView.

**Question:** How can I sort the ListView by the Person's status ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a `Status` property to your `Person` type and bind to that in your grid instead. If you don't wish to add a `Status` property to your model, then you could create a `PersonViewModel` instead with this additional property, and bind your grid to a collection of `PersonViewModel`.